# How to perform an insert with an argument and a query

Tags: php, database, postgresql, insert

In my database I have a table TABLE(person, match).
I'm trying to insert values in this table but I get a sintax error, I think I'm writing the query wrong.

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO table ($1, SELECT id FROM match_import) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING; ";
   $result = pg_prepare($dbh, "", $query);
   $result = pg_execute($dbh, "", array($user));
```

The first value is an argument passed with the pg_execute, but the second one (match) is taken from another table in the database.

I get this error

> Error: Warning: pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" LINE 1: INSERT INTO table ($1, SELECT id FROM match_import) ON CON... ^ in /Applications/mappstack-7.1.27-2/apache2/htdocs...

How can I solve these problem?

Comment: If your table name is `insert`, then you will have to escape this as it will most likely be a reserved word.  Also it always help if you include the error text if you are getting any as this would help.

Comment: @NigelRen I changed the table's name as you suggested and edited the post with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the argument to the query:

```
INSERT INTO table(column1, column2)
SELECT $1, id FROM match_import
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
```